# In Symfony, is this the best way to prevent duplicates in custom ManyToMany

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I have a ManyToMany relationship between Person and FooBar, but the join table needs a couple of extra fields. So I create my own join Entity PersonFooBar, and set Person and FooBar to have OneToMany relationships to PersonFooBar.

This works okay but allows me to add duplicates which I don't want.

To prevent this I have added some code to the add function in the Person anbd FooBar Entities.

So instead of this

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Company\MyBundle\Entity\PersonFooBar", mappedBy="person")
     */
    protected $person_foo_bars;

    /**
     * Add person_foo_bar
     *
     * @param \Company\MyBundle\Entity\PersonFooBar $personFooBar
     * @return Person
     */
    public function addSurgeryTray(\Company\SurgeryBundle\Entity\PersonFooBar $personFooBar)
    {
        $this->person_foo_bars[] = $personFooBar;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have this

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Company\MyBundle\Entity\PersonFooBar", mappedBy="person")
     */
    protected $person_foo_bars;

    /**
     * Add person_foo_bar
     *
     * @param \Company\MyBundle\Entity\PersonFooBar $personFooBar
     * @return Person
     */
    public function addSurgeryTray(\Company\SurgeryBundle\Entity\PersonFooBar $personFooBar)
    {
        // Only add if the new personfooBar is for a new fooBar
        $fooBarIds = array();
        foreach ($this->person_foo_bars as $currentPersonFooBar) {
            $fooBarIds[] = $currentPersonFooBar->getFooBar()->getId();
        }
        if (!in_array($personFooBar->getFooBar()->getId(), $fooBarIds)) {
            $this->person_foo_bars[] = $personFooBar;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Just set an unique index for person_id and foobar_id

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to do everything before I flush() the entity manager. I don't have to worry about catching UniqueConstraintViolationException then dealing with the entity manager closing.

Comment: There is an indexBy parameter which would allow indexing personFooBars by the id.  And there is no real need to build fooBarIds.  Just check the id in the loop and return if found.